# Regex match the last group with @ character on the first character match

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i match this string `permission grant inspire @you @me @john` like this match

```
Group 1: grant or deny

Group 2: anything character

Group 3: should match start with @ every character in match like @you @me you and this is splitted by splace
```

This is my try in regex `^permission\s(grant|deny)\s(.*)\s(.*)`

this is my [fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/2oWHpt/1)

Note: I'm using javascript, does this need lookbehinds or something else that can look around

Comment: Try: `/^permission\s(grant|deny)\s([^@]+)\s(.*)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may consider this regex:

```sh
^permission\s(grant|deny)\s([^@]+)\s(.*)
```

Last group has this pattern `([^@]+)` that matches 1+ of any character that is not a `@` so that our match stops at the first `@` later.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2oWHpt/2)